# WPF Loading multiple tabs simultaneously in background with freezing UI

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, tabcontrol, tabitem

[Basic UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFrp1.png)

I have UI shown in above image.

Each Tab have Some controls like grid which has some data filled in from datatable.

**What i want?**
behaviour just like web browsers when we open new tab, it gets loaded in background.
Entire browser doesn't freeze. you are able to see and interact with facebook if twitter is loading in another tab.

**How it is behaving currently ?**

When i click on one of the item in left hand side treeview , tab gets opened but it freezes entire UI of the app, i am not able to click on another treeview item until the tab has completed its data into grid.

**Current Implementation**

on treeview click event, another thread is created which is calling addTab()
function.

```
treeviewlist_SelectedItemChanged()
{
   Dim thread As New Thread(Sub() Me.AddTab( itemno))
   thread.Start()
 }
```

below function creates backgroundWorker thread object bw, 
bg_dowork() gets datatable from DB to bind to the grid in tabitem.
bg_RunWorkerCompleted() binds that dt to grid in tabitem.

```
Addtab()

{
  Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Function() 

    Dim bg As New BackgroundWorker

      AddHandler bg.DoWork, Sub(sender, e)
       //get dt
      End Sub

     AddHandler bg.RunWorkerCompleted, Sub(sender, e)
     // bind dt to grid
    End Sub
   Return 1
    End Function),    DispatcherPriority.Send)

 }
```

To be honest i am new to WPF and vb.net and somehow feel i have messed up somewhere badly.

Comment: Why are you creating a thread when the only thing you do in that thread is invoking a method? (And in that method you are for some reason trying to perform multithreading again??) When you call `Dispatcher.(Begin)Invoke()` you are moving the execution to the UI thread. -- What you're doing right now is just redundant! You create a new thread only to execute code on the UI thread where you create a background worker to perform multithreading again. You never even start your BGW. Either do everything in your thread and invoke when you need to access the UI, or just use a BGW from the beginning.

Comment: _Either do everything in your thread and invoke when you need to access the UI_  **Is it possible to create entire Tab Item dynamically, get datatable from DB , bind it to grid in Thread and attaching the tab item to Tab Control which is created on Main thread?**

Comment: Yes, if you only invoke once you are to access the UI then you can do almost anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is c# code. But it explains the concept nicely. It uses async/await keywords. The for-loop below can be replaced with your data-access code.

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
...    
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await _loadEmployees();
}

private Task _loadEmployees()
{
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

        for (long i = 0; i < 999999; ++i)
            employees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Name" + i, Address = DateTime.Now.ToString() });

        vm.Employees = employees;
    });

    return t;
}
```

`DataGrid` is bound to `Employees` property of `ViewModel` .

Set `Width` and `Height` of `DataGrid` so that `DataGrid` can use `UIVirtualization`.

You can ask more doubts, I will update here.